# Return RegExp C# with linebreak

Tags: c#, regex

I’m having a problem with Regular Expressions in C#.
What I have is a string representing a page (HTML etc.). The string also contains \r\n, \r and \n in different places, now I’m trying to match something in the string:

```
Match currentMatch = Regex.Match(contents, "Title: <strong>(.*?)</strong>");
string org = currentMatch.Groups[1].ToString();
```

This works fine, however, when I want to match something that has any of the characters mentioned earlier (line breaks) in the string, it doesn’t return anything (empty, no match):

```
Match currentMatch = Regex.Match(contents, "Description: <p>(.*?)</p>");
string org = currentMatch.Groups[1].ToString();
```

It does however work if I add the following lines above the match:

```
contents = contents.Replace("\r", " ");
contents = contents.Replace("\n", " ");
```

I however don’t like that its modify the source, what can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` does not match newline characters by default. You can change this, by using the [Regex Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx) `Singleline`. This treats the whole input string as one line, i.e. the dot matches also newline characters.

```
Match currentMatch = Regex.Match(contents, "Title: <strong>(.*?)</strong>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

By the way, I hope you are aware that regex is normally not the way to deal with Html?

Comment: Hello, and thanks a lot. What is the better way to deal with HTML? I've always used Regular Expressions in other languages aswell. Thanks

Comment: Use a HTML parser, see for example this question: [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)